# Changing database structure and migrating password hashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design, bcrypt

I currently have a site (Rails 4.1, ActiveRecord, Postgres) where a visitor can log in to one of multiple models — for example, a visitor can create an account or login as a `User`, `Artist`, etc. Each of these models have a `password_digest` column (using `bcrypt` and `has_secure_password`).

Now we want to move to the site to a unified login system — everyone creates and logs in as a `User`, and a `User` can belong to an `Artist` and the other models we have.

I think it makes sense to directly use the `password_digest` column in the `User` table, rather than looking across all the existing models. This means we'll have to create new entries in the `User` table and copy the `password_digest`s into them.

**Can this be safely done, and would everyone be able to login with the password they already have?** I've tried playing around with `password_digest`s in the Rails console (copying digests to known passwords and assigning them to other entries) and it appears to authenticate correctly … are there any downsides to doing this?

Comment: "Portable" is the term I'm looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19079799/are-rails-passwords-generated-with-bcrypt-portable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no uniqueness constraint on passwords (i assume) and so it doesn't matter if the passwords are the same between different User accounts (in the resulting table, with all the Artist etc records copied in).  There's no safety issues with copying the data from one table/column to another: there's nothing magical about the `password_digest` value, it's just a text string.  As long as you carry on using the same encryption method then the crypted password you generate to test on login should still match the saved value.

You may have a problem with usernames though, if they are required to be unique:  what happens if you have an existing User and an existing Artist who have the same username?  Is one of them going to have to change?

Comment: Thanks! Emails are the only unique identifier we have across the whole site, and fortunately we don't have any duplicates there yet

Comment: Cool.  You should be fine then :)